# Can I buy 3rd-party tech support incidents for iphone development?

Tags: iphone

Instead of buying technical support for $195 from ADC, can anyone recommend another way to buy tech support for iphone development troubleshooting?

Answer (score 2):

You could hire an independent iPhone developer to assist you with your problem. They will likely charge hourly [(they can charge in the neighborhood of $125 to $200 per hour)](http://blogs.oreilly.com/iphone/2008/11/turning-ideas-into-application.html) and you'll have to do your homework to make sure they're up to snuff.

Alternatively you can just ask your questions here! We'll help for free!

Answer (score 2):

How about Stackoverflow?

Comment: Excellent answer, plus, we're free inasmuch as we're paid in worthless SO$.

Comment: It's a circular reference Q&A ;-)

Answer (score 0):

You can hire an [iPhone developer on oDesk.com](http://www.odesk.com/trends/iPhone) for around $25/hour.  You can upload your project to the free/secure SVN hosting, and allow a provider to look at it / debug it.  Communication can be a bit difficult at times, and time zones and deadlines often means this won't be the fastest way to get a bug fixed.

Another idea is to see if there's a [meeting group in your area](http://www.google.com/search?q=iphone+site%3Ameetup.com).  You can have a hack-a-thon where people meet up and help each other with their code.